# Not All Flavours CodeChef DSA Learning Week 2

Tags: java, arrays

The question state that there are N pieces of K different flavoured cakes in unordered manner. I need to print the maximum length of the continuous segment where at least one of the flavour get missing.
Ex. if N=20 K=6 and array is 6 6 6 6 2 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 3 2 4 5 6 1 3 then it should print 11 as the length from 8th element to 18th element is max and flavour 1 is missing.
I have tried all the test cases that I can make it off and all the test cases passed very well. But on submitting it gives Wrong Answer. Can someone help me out where am i going wrong in this question.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Codechef{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt(),a[];
        long n,k,count=0,max=0;
        while(t--!=0){
            n=sc.nextLong();
            k=sc.nextLong();
            a=new int[(int)n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            if(k>n) System.out.println(n);
            else{
                for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                        if(a[j]==i) count=0;
                        else{
                            count++;
                            max=max>count?max:count;
                        }
                    }
                    if(count==n) break;
                    count=0;
                }
            System.out.println(max);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code.

Comment: I think it would help if you explained here in this Question what the code is suppose to do. All posts here have to be self-contained. Meaning all the information needs to be within this Question itself. A link is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks and i will we careful enough from next time.

Comment: What do you mean "from next time"? You can edit your Question to include it.